# pdfbox java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have program to reading pdf. I'm using library pdfbox for java.
Most pdf was loading and i get text. But in one pdf i get:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Value >is not an integer: >86714696448948619000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser$1.tryNext(PDFStreamParser.java:191)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser$1.hasNext(PDFStreamParser.java:198)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:255)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:460)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:385)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:344)

at  in line 12  (String x1 = stripper.getText(doc);)

```
 PDDocument doc  ;    

 doc = PDDocument.load(file.getPath());
 if(doc!=null){
 stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
 stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
 stripper.setStartPage( 28 );
 stripper.setEndPage(doc.getNumberOfPages());//Integer.MAX_VALUE );
 PDFParser parser;
 parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
 parser.parse();
 String x1 = stripper.getText(doc);
```

Anybody know how to repair that or around this problem

Comment: Two points: i) Is the PDF you are reading encrypted? 2) As not your code, but the code in the PDFStreamParser fails: could you add the release number of the library, e.g. 1.8.3?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but you don't need the three lines with "parser". load() is enough. Better: PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file, null); .

Comment: 1. PDF is not Encrypted. 2. 1.8.3 and 1.8.6 tested.(this same resoult)
I can't share this pdf, because in company this pdf is secret.
I try function loadnonseq, but this same result.

Comment: Please try again with an 1.8.8 snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.8-SNAPSHOT/